# is the regular expression "|" supposed to match everything or only the empty string?

Tags: c#, java, regex, pipe

In .NET it matches everything.  In Java only empty string.

That's just the way their regex engines are implemented.

But how can I force the .NET regex engine to match | against only the empty string or the Java regex engine to match it against everything?

Comment: can you explain the problem with sample code?

Comment: i thought the pipe character `|` (in nearly all regex flavours) is a meta-character for specifying alternate patterns

Comment: I think you'll be hard pressed to tell the regex engine to behave differently (you can set it to parse as EMCAscript however), it would probably be easier to write code to explicitly check for empty strings before using regex.

Answer (score 6):

`|` is OR for regular expressions in java:

`X|Y` --> Either `X` or `Y`

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the character `|` in a regular expression is an [operator that matches the expressions on either side of the pipe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Depending on what you mean by match everything, in Java you can use `.*`, which matches any character zero or more times.

Answer (score 1):

`|` stands for regular `OR` Operation.

**More information:**

Source http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

If you want to search for the literal text `cat` or `dog`, separate both options with a vertical bar or pipe symbol `|` : `cat|dog`.

If you want more options, simply expand the list: `cat|dog|mouse|fish`.

Hope it helps! :)